# Batch File - Delete Files Based Off Number In File Name

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a task assigned to me that I know how to do it other languages, but the Windows batch/cmd requirement has me a little baffled.

There is a directory with several files:

- FileName0.txt
- FileName0-2014.txt
- FileName0-2013.txt
- FileName1.txt
- FileName1-2014.txt
- FileName1-2013.txt
- FileName2.txt
- FileName2-2014.txt
- FileName2-2013.txt

That same pattern might repeat all the way up to FileName54.txt and so on. Also keep in mind I have simplified the examples for various reasons, but the format of the names is the same.

Essentially there are main files (FileName0.txt, FileName1.txt, etc) and then truncated files from earlier (FileName1-2014.txt, FileName1-2013.txt, etc) and each set that number can be anything from 0 to whatever...Highest I've seen is 54 but that could change.

What I need to do is have a batch/cmd file that would keep all the FileName0*.tx files, the main files for the other number sequences (FileName1.txt, FileName2.txt, etc), and then delete all the other truncated files for any of the sequences other than the FileName0 set.

I figured I can focus on the "-" after the sequence number, so basically delete FileName1-*.txt, but trying to figure out a systematic way to make that work for all sequences above 0 is perplexing me.

Thoughts/Comments/Examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
FOR %%a IN (filenames*.txt) DO FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=-" %%s IN ("%%a") DO IF "%%t"=="" SET "keep=%%~na"&GOTO nextstep
:nextstep
ECHO keep %keep%*
FOR %%a IN (filenames*-*.txt) DO FOR /f "tokens=1,2delims=-" %%s IN ("%%a") DO IF "%%s" neq "%keep%" ECHO DEL "%%a"

GOTO :EOF
```

The required DEL commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO DEL` to `DEL` to actually delete the files.

(I've changed the template to `filenameS` to suit my testing)

Comment: Need to do some more testing but the initial tests look perfect! I assume the first line of code is finding all the filenames0 and the second is deleting everything but those right? The "neq" is for not equal to right?

Comment: Correct on all counts.

Answer (score 1):

The ugly way misusing access rights:

```
attrib +r FileName0*.txt
del FileName*-*.txt
attrib -r FileName0*.txt
```

The nicer way:

```
for /L %i in (1,1,999) DO del FileName%i-*.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%f in (
  'dir /a-d /b *.txt ^| findstr /r /c:"FileName[1-9][0-9]*-"'
) do echo del "%%~ff"
```

Filter the list of files to retrieve only the required ones.